# Disable TLSv1.0 in spring boot v 1.4.0 with embedded jetty v 9.2.13

Tags: spring-boot

I want to disable TLSv1.0 in spring boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE. We are using embedded jetty version 9.2.13.v20150730 with spring boot.

I don't think this is possible with the spring boot properties. I have tried following but the TLSv1 is still enabled.

```
server.ssl.protocol TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

So i checked the spring boot auto configuration code. And here is how the SSLContext for Jetty is getting initialized

There is no factory.setExcludeProtocols method call from the following configureSsl method. Even though the SslContextFactory has the setExcludeProtocols method in it.

Can you please add the server.ssl.disabled-protocols property in spring boot? or if this is already possible to disable the TLSv1.0 please let me know.

```
/**
 * Configure the SSL connection.
 * @param factory the Jetty {@link SslContextFactory}.
 * @param ssl the ssl details.
 */
protected void configureSsl(SslContextFactory factory, Ssl ssl) {
    factory.setProtocol(ssl.getProtocol());
    configureSslClientAuth(factory, ssl);
    configureSslPasswords(factory, ssl);
    factory.setCertAlias(ssl.getKeyAlias());
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(ssl.getCiphers())) {
        factory.setIncludeCipherSuites(ssl.getCiphers());
        factory.setExcludeCipherSuites();
    }
    if (ssl.getEnabledProtocols() != null) {
        factory.setIncludeProtocols(ssl.getEnabledProtocols());
    }
    if (getSslStoreProvider() != null) {
        try {
            factory.setKeyStore(getSslStoreProvider().getKeyStore());
            factory.setTrustStore(getSslStoreProvider().getTrustStore());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to set SSL store", ex);
        }
    }
    else {
        configureSslKeyStore(factory, ssl);
        configureSslTrustStore(factory, ssl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way that i found is to set ciphers that are supported only by TLSv1.2.
Ex:
If you will put in application.yml

```
server.ssl.ciphers:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

And the using CURL

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1
```

You will see that request will be ignored / rejected because that cipher that you set in application.yml will validate only TLSv1.2 requests.